# Possible Number Combos That I can not figure out

Tags: recreational-mathematics, combinations

I am wondering,

I have 
4 QB's,
8 RB's,
12 WR's,
4 TE's,
4 K's,
4 Def,

I can only play
1 QB,
2 RB's,
3 WR's,
1 TE,
1 K,
1 DEF

for a total of nine players.

How many different combinations do I have?

Thanks!

Thane

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** There are $\binom{4}{1}$ ways to choose the QB. *For each such way*, there are $\binom{8}{2}$ ways to choose the RB's. *For every way* of choosing the QB and the RB's, there are $\binom{12}{3}$ ways to choose the WR's. And so on.